# How can i remove duplicate Google Analytics code in my website?

Tags: google-analytics

**what i have tried**

I have installed Monster Insights plugin in my Wordpress site. I have also put GA code in theme options previously, but later I removed it because google tag manager extension is showing multiple tracking ids.

**Problem**

Now also there are multiple tracking code implemented in my site and thus showing incorrect stats in Google analytics .
Step by Step Solution would be appreciable :)

Note : There is no GA code in header.php file in theme editor neither in Theme options , whats the solution then to remove duplicate GA Code.

Comment: Show same screenshot please

Comment: Hi, could you share the URL of your site? That could help the community to understand what is going on there.

Comment: [link]https://www.vtexvsi.com -- @Hernan

Comment: @Michele Pisani -  https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vlQ2g9aGk8RKwqrEgHcs6hhA9r4xpKi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I only want to keep Monster Insights code

Comment: @Michele Pisani also check this -- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g5Yu-wlxIri_x-rtHOnT_qyZX_5r0ArE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It takes authorization to access the files, anyway you have 2 snippet in page. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

what I see going on on that site:

1. The gtag.js in the header. Looks good, could be the code that you setup in your theme (it's impossible to tell by the source code).
2. The Tag Manager tag. You should check in Tag Manager if there is an Analytics tag set up there, but it doesn't look suspicious.
3. Some code in the footer that starts with  and declares again your tag. It looks like the Monsters Insight script.

I also see that you are running a cache plugin. Given that you say that you already removed the code, the most likely cause is the cache plugin preventing your updated settings to show. That means that even if you removed the code from your theme settings, it could still be showing up. Your last cache is from 22-05-20 14:06:14, could it be the cause? There is a Clear Cache link in your admin bar, you should try clearing if your changes were from yesterday after 14:06:14 (probably server timezone).

Hope it helps, regards!

Answer (score 0):

In your website there is a code in head that use `gtag`, and another injected by MonsterInsights plugin.

Comment: Then how do I find and remove other codes which are not injected by MonsterInsights

Comment: Try to check setup options in other plugins

Comment: But as of now, there is only MonsterInsights plugin installed and so receiving late and incorrect stats in GA sometimes.

Comment: GTM seems not send any hits, so if there aren't other plugin it may be a setting in theme option or check in head/header file.